# Visual Studio Debug Error

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I recently added some multi-threading to my project. Now, I am getting the following error in debug mode:

```
Debug Error!

Program: C:\src\grok-build\bin\Debug\opj_decompress.exe

abort() has been called

(Press Retry to debug the application)
The program '[20468] opj_decompress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the dialog popping up allowing me to debug the program, it simply just exits. How can I find the problem here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not joining the threads before exiting.